# Qt 5.4 - Mac OS X 10.6 Support

Tags: macos, qt

I compiled my App using Qt 5.3.2 on my Mac OS X 10.9 and it runs on Mac OS X 10.6 without any issue. But due to a bug in Qt 5.3.2 (unfixed) which causes the apps to crash on maximizing, if focus is on tree view, I had to switch to Qt 5.4.

After compiling my app using Qt 5.4 on Mac OS X 10.9, it no more runs on Mac OS X 10.6. It crashes with the error:

```
dyld: library not loaded: /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib Qt
```

Answer (score 4):

After some searching I figured out that

Running Qt apps on Mac OS X 10.6 is not supported by Qt 5.4 binaries available on Qt Website. A custom build is required for the same.

**As per one source:**

**To make clang++ produce binaries compatible with g++ from llvm-gcc-4.2.1, use these compiler and linker flags: -stdlib=libstdc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.6**

**These will make sure we link with the 10.6 CRT and that we do not link with libc++ (the default C++ library for clang++).**

For custom build:

```
./configure -prefix $PWD/qtbase -opensource -no-c++11 -debug-and-release -nomake examples -nomake demos
```

Comment: I have put a great deal of effort into building 5.3.2 on 10.6 and as part of this effort I have built it in C++11 mode by first building LLVM 3.5, then using it to build `libc++` and `libc++abi`, then placing these libraries in `/usr/lib`. I then was able with mild editing of Qt's sources to build 5.3.2 against `libc++` using Clang. I expect the first part of this procedure should yield you the `libc++` dylibs you need to progress further, even with Qt 5.4.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist I am not building on 10.6, i am just targeting 10.6 as min supported version

Comment: But can you not build those 10.6 `libc++`'es and ship them with the app on 10.6? You may use `install_name_tool` to make the binaries and Qt libs point to `@loader_path/libc++.1.dylib` as opposed to `/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib`. But I suppose that if you've managed to build 5.4 binaries that work for you in 10.6, that is enough.

Answer (score 0):

10.6 is no longer supported in Qt 5.4

If you even compile it manually using -no-c++11, your app resulting executable will crash on 10.6

5.3.2 is the last to support 10.6 with -no-c++11